# Optimizar consulta en laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo un problema con dicha consulta que tarda hasta 5 minutos en cargar el problema proviene cuando agrego el join:

> ->join('metodos_de_pago', 'metodos_de_pago.id_usuario', '=', 'historial_de_pagos.id_usuario')

Si ese join la consulta anda rapido pero al agregarla tarda demasiado en carga y si se realiza una busqueda esta se torna peor de lenta

```
$historiales = Historial::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'historial_de_pagos.id_usuario')
        ->join('metodos_de_pago', 'metodos_de_pago.id_usuario', '=', 'historial_de_pagos.id_usuario')
        ->select('historial_de_pagos.*', 'users.documento', 'users.nombre', 'users.tipo_documento', 'users.pais', 'metodos_de_pago.banco as banco', 'metodos_de_pago.tipo_aplicacion  as tipo_aplicacion', 'metodos_de_pago.metodo_de_pago  as metodo_de_pago')  
        ->when($banco, function ($historiales, $banco) {                
            return $historiales->where('banco','like',"%$banco%");
        })
        ->when($tipo_aplicacion, function ($historiales, $tipo_aplicacion) {                
            return $historiales->where('tipo_aplicacion','like',"%$tipo_aplicacion%");
        })
        ->when($user_id, function ($historiales, $user_id) {                
            return $historiales->where('users.id','like',"%$user_id%");
        })
        ->when($pais, function ($historiales, $pais) {                
            return $historiales->where('pais_pago','like',"%$pais%");
        })
        ->when($registro, function ($historiales, $registro) {                
            return $historiales->where('historial_de_pagos.registro','like',"%$registro%");
        })->when($estado, function ($historiales, $estado) {                
            return $historiales->where('status','like',"%$estado%");
        }) ->when($pais, function ($historiales, $pais) {                
            return $historiales->where('historial_de_pagos.pais_pago','like',"%$pais%");
        })              
       ->when($estado, function ($historiales, $estado) {                
           return $historiales->where('historial_de_pagos.status','like',"%$estado%");
       })
       ->when($plataforma, function ($historiales, $plataforma) {                
           return $historiales->where('historial_de_pagos.plataforma','like',"%$plataforma%");
       })
       ->when($idplataforma, function ($historiales, $idplataforma) {                
           return $historiales->where('historial_de_pagos.id_plataforma','like',"%$idplataforma%");
       })
       ->when($moneda, function ($historiales, $moneda) {                
           return $historiales->where('historial_de_pagos.tipo_moneda','like',"%$moneda%");
       })               
       ->when($valor, function ($historiales, $valor) {                
           return $historiales->where('historial_de_pagos.valor','like',"%$valor%");
       })               
       ->when($fechainicio, function ($historiales, $fechainicio) {
           $fechainicio = new Carbon($fechainicio);      
           return $historiales->whereDate('historial_de_pagos.fecha_pago', '>=', $fechainicio->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s'));
       })
       ->when($fechafin, function ($historiales, $fechafin) {
           $fechafin = new Carbon($fechafin);
           return $historiales->whereDate('historial_de_pagos.fecha_pago', '<=', $fechafin->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s'));
       })

       ->orderBy('historial_de_pagos.id','desc');
```

Comment: ya probaste la consulta con script nativo en tu motor?, si tienes el mismo tiempo de respuesta ya no es un tema de eloquent sino de la consulta